# Symfony path not open link but work in new tab

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig, materialize

In my project Symfony I'm listing categories, everything works fine visually and the links appear correctly.

But un my project when I left click  the website did nothing and when I select open in a new tab my link  works and appear correctly.

The error is coming from this part of my code :

```
<div class="nav-content">
        <ul class="tabs tabs-transparent">
            {% for categorie in  categories.categories %}
                <li class="tab"><a target="_blank" class="black-text" href="{{ path('client.constructeurs.view', {CategorieParentId: categorie.id }) }}">{{ categorie.categorieIntitule }}</a></li>
             {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
```

On the Mobile demo it works correctly :

```
{% for categorie in  categories.categories %}
        <li class="tab black-text"><a class="black-text" href="{{path('client.constructeurs.view', {CategorieParentId: categorie.id }) }}">{{ categorie.categorieIntitule }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
```

Any idea ?

Here is my code :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="nav-extended white ">
    <div class="nav-wrapper ">
        <a href="#" class="brand-logo"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x60.png" alt="Logo Spie"></a>
        <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="black-text material-icons">menu</i></a>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down black-text">
            <li>
                <div class="center row ">
                    <div class="col s12 " >
                        <div class="row" id="topbarsearch">
                            <div class="input-field col s6 s12 black-text">
                                <i class="black-text material-icons prefix">search</i>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="search" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete black-text" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="black-text"><a class="black-text" href="sass.html"> SASS</a></li>
            <li><a class="black-text" href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
            <li><a class="black-text" href="#">Mon Compte</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-content">
        <ul class="tabs tabs-transparent">
            {% for categorie in  categories.categories %}
                <li class="tab"><a class="black-text" href="{{ path('client.constructeurs.view', {CategorieParentId: categorie.id }) }}">{{ categorie.categorieIntitule }}</a></li>
             {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
    {% for categorie in  categories.categories %}
        <li class="tab black-text"><a class="black-text" href="{{path('client.constructeurs.view', {CategorieParentId: categorie.id }) }}">{{ categorie.categorieIntitule }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mon Compte</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you clarify? Which link does not work?

Comment: I'm sorry I've edited my question

Comment: whenever a link works when right-clicking it and doesn't when left-clicking, I usually assume some javascript problem. from a html view, links are generally followed, although an effect might be missing, if the url has an anchor (`...#something`) and the actual path is identical (and anchor might be too)

Comment: If you remove the `target="_blank"` ?

Comment: Can your clarify your question?

Comment: My target Blank was here only for the text, it works correctly with a target blank but without it it makes nothing. Nothing print on the console too. I've compared withe the Front framework but I cant't realize if I made a mistake or my extended navbar is only here to male anchors ?  :  http://archives.materializecss.com/0.100.2/navbar.html#navbar-tabs

Comment: Going on a limb here... is it possible that you have some `jQuery` script which intercepts all click events `<a>` which do not have `target` attribute? I've seen scary stuff like that in the past...